# MVVM XAML and.net Maui issue when using query attribute

Tags: data-binding

Data being pulled from the web server is displayed in a live market page but not on another view which summarises the data

Using the iquery attribute but not sure why it’s not working

Trying to take the results from the web server and display in a summary page
However it returns a blank
If I use a test display from the same page it works. Not sure what I’m missing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLzom.jpg)